# How to install intellij-haskell plugin?

Tags: haskell, plugins, intellij-idea, installation

Haskell-cafe mentioned a new [plugin](https://github.com/rikvdkleij/intellij-haskell) for programming Haskell in IntelliJ IDEA.

It's not obvious to me how to install it.  Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Have you looked at the Install Instructions in https://github.com/carymrobbins/intellij-haskforce/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide ?

Comment: But intellij-haskell does not have a installable ZIP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Download](https://github.com/rikvdkleij/intellij-haskell/archive/master.zip) plugin from GitHub

In IntelliJ:

```
File | Settings | Plugins | Install Plugin from disk...
```

in opened dialog window choose your plugin `.zip` file press <kbd>OK</kbd> and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

You can download releases from [Releases](https://github.com/rikvdkleij/intellij-haskell/releases) page as installable zip.

Releases are also uploaded to Jetbrains plugins repository. Version 0.1 is available, version 0.2 is currently waiting for approval.

Comment: In the meantime version 0.2 is approved.